# Event handler in vs extensibility

Tags: visual-studio, vsx

How can I handle events such as item added, renamed or deleted in a project in visual studio extensibility?

Comment: This article should have exactly what you're looking for: http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005009.aspx